# How can I set default parameter value to BigInteger type?

Tags: c#, biginteger

I need to have a class that has a constructor with BigInteger type. I'd like to set a default value to 0 to it with this code, but I got compile error.

```
public class Hello
{
    BigInteger X {get; set;}
    public Hello(BigInteger x = 0)
    {
        X = x;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void RunSnippet()
    {
        var h = new Hello(); // Error <--
```

What's wrong? Is there way to set default value to BigInteger parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default parameters only work compile time constants (and value types where the parameter can be `default(ValType)` or `new ValType()`), and as such don't work for BigInteger. For your case, you could perhaps do something like this; providing a constructor overload that takes int, and make that have a default parameter:

```
public Hello(int x = 0) : this(new BigInteger(x)) {}
public Hello(BigInteger x) 
{
    X = x;
}
```

In case you are wondering, the `x = 0` doesn't count as a constant when the type is a `BigInteger`, because converting 0 to `BigInteger` would [involve invoking the implicit conversion operator for int to BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268348.aspx).

Comment: Default parameters don't work just for integral types. You can do something like `string s = null`.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, since the default value you want is zero, you can use the default `BigInteger` constructor because `BigInteger` is a value type:

```
public class Hello
{
    BigInteger X { get; set; }

    public Hello(BigInteger x = new BigInteger())
    {
        X = x;
    }
}
```

This will not work with values besides zero because the expression must be a [compile time constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

> Each optional parameter has a default value as part of its definition. If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used. A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

Comment: But something like `42` *is* a compile-time constant.

Comment: @svick: But unfortunately `42` is not convertible to a `BigInteger` so it is a compile-time constant but illegal for a different reason.

Comment: but `42` is convertible to `BigInteger`. [There is an implicit conversion from `int` to `BigInteger`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268348.aspx)

Comment: You are correct.  The error message is actually: A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no **standard** conversions to type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' (emphasis added).

Answer (score 2):

Use an overloaded constructor

```
public class Hello
{
    BigInteger X {get; set;}
    public Hello(BigInteger x)
    {
        X = x;
    }
    public Hello()
    {
        X = new BigInteger(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From §10.6.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> The *expression* in a *default-argument* must be one of the following:
>
> - a *constant-expression*
> - an expression of the form `new S()` where `S` is a value type
> - an expression of the form `default(S)` where `S` is a value type
>
> The *expression* must be implicitly convertible by an identity or nullable conversion to the type of the parameter.

What this means for `BigInteger` is that the only option for default argument is to use 0, expressed either as `new BigInteger()` or `default(BigInteger)`.

`BigInteger x = 0` doesn't work, because `0` is of type `int` and the implicit conversion from `int` to `BigInteger` is not “an identity or nullable conversion”.

If you want the default argument to be anything else other than 0, you have several options:

- use `BigInteger?`, let the default be `null` and at the beginning of the method check for that. If the parameter is `null`, set it to the default value.
- create another overload of the method that takes e.g. `int` with the default argument specified. This method in turn calls the `BigInteger` overload that doesn't have the default argument. This assumes the default value fits in an `int`, but I think that should be the case most of the time.